# A heap class implemetation

Tags: c++, object-oriented, heap

```
     /*insert(int value)
     shift_up(i) - needed for insert
     get_max - returns the max item, without removing it
     get_size() - return number of elements stored
     is_empty() - returns true if heap contains no elements
     extract_max - returns the max item, removing it
     shift_down(i) - needed for extract_max
     remove(i) - removes item at index x
     heapify - create a heap from an array of elements, needed for 
     heap_sort
     heap_sort() - take an unsorted array and turn it into a sorted 
     array in-place using a max heap*/
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <climits>
    using namespace std;
    class heap{
    public:
        heap();
        heap(const heap& other);
        heap& operator=(heap src);
        ~heap();
        int parent(int i);
        int right_child(int i);
        int left_child(int i);
        void insert(int value);
        void shift_up(int i);
        int get_max();
        int get_size();
        bool is_empty();
        int extract_max();
        void shift_down(int i);
        void remove(int i);
        void heapify(const vector<int>&); //Build array into a heap
        void heap_sort(const vector<int>&);
        void display();
    private:
        vector<int> v;
        int size;
    };
    // only constructer is needed as we are using a built in library so no destructor
    heap::heap():size(0),v({0}){}

    heap::heap(const heap& other){
        size = other.size;
        v = other.v;
    }

    heap& heap::operator=(heap src){
        swap(size, src.size);
        swap(v,src.v);
    }

    heap::~heap(){}

    int heap::parent(int i){
        return floor(i/2);
    }
    int heap::left_child(int i){
        return 2*i;
    }
    int heap::right_child(int i){
        return 2*i + 1;
    }
    void heap::insert(int value){
        v.push_back(value);
        size += 1;
        shift_up(size);
    }
    void heap::shift_up(int i){
        while (i > 1 && (v[parent(i)] < v[i])){
            swap(v[parent(i)], v[i]);
            i = parent(i);
        }
    }

    int heap::get_max(){
        return v[1];
    }

    int heap::get_size(){
        return size;
    }
    bool heap::is_empty(){
        bool k;
        (size>0)? k = true: k = false;
        return k;
    }
    int heap::extract_max(){

        int maxi = v[1];

        v[1] = v[size];

        size -= 1;

        shift_down(1);

        return maxi;
    }
    void heap::shift_down(int i){
        int maxIndex = i; 

        int l = left_child(i);

        if(l <= size && v[maxIndex] < v[l])
            maxIndex = l;

        int r = right_child(i);

        if(r <= size && v[maxIndex] < v[r])
            maxIndex = r;

        if (i != maxIndex){
            swap(v[i], v[maxIndex]);
            shift_down(maxIndex);
        }
    }
    void heap::remove(int value){
    int i = 0;
    int focus;
        while(i <= size){
            if(v.at(i) == value){
                focus = i;
                break;
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        v[focus] = INT_MAX;
        shift_up(focus);
        extract_max();
    }
    void heap::heapify(const vector<int>& A){
        v.resize(A.size()+1);
        size = A.size();
        int j = 1;
        for(auto x: A){
            v[j] = x;
            j++;
        }
        for(int i = parent(size) ; i >= 1 ; i--){  //running time n 
            shift_down(i);
        }
    }
    void heap::heap_sort(const vector<int> &A){
        heapify(A);

        while(size > 1){
            swap(v[1],v[size]);
            size -= 1;
            shift_down(1);
        }
    }
    void heap::display(){
        for(auto x: v)
            cout << x << " ";
    }
```

Please suggest possible good code management techniques which can help me write and maintain better code in the future. I think implementing and maintaining data structures could be a good practice on how to maintain code for beginners like me.

Comment: The first step should be to fix the [warnings and errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d82d06630d6f1c5) when you compile this code.

Comment: I have compiled using c++14. That doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Got you. In my g++ compiler it doesn't show warning. I will find a way so that it starts showing me warning as well.

Comment: @RupankPahuja, use `-Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`. The latter might be overkill in some limited cases, but the first two are usually always used.

Comment: are the "needed-for" functions (shift*, heapify) part of the heap user interface? if not they should be "hidden" somehow, either declared/defined locally or in the private section of the class

Comment: @RupankPahuja: Maybe no errors. But if you turn on warnings `-Wall -Wextra` I see 6 warnings. Two seem critical three will cause errors in the long term and the last one is good advice. Remember the "Warnings" by the C++ compiler are logical errors in your understanding of the code. They may be technically legal syntax but will usually result in bugs or undefined behavior.

Comment: @Incomputable: I always use `-Werror` it prevents compilation when you have logical bugs.

Comment: @MartinYork, compiler sometimes errs on my templates, which I abuse. I haven’t seen problems with that yet, but I’m not professional by any means.

Answer (score 1):

1. use the correct numeric domain for your types, e.g. `unsigned` instead of `int` for size since negative size is never valid for any data structure. It also simplifies some of the error handling.
2. `using namespace` in header is a big no-no. If you want to omit `std::` in you code you need to localize it, like putting typedefs inside the class declaration or having a .cpp seperate from .h.
3. `is_empty` might as well return the ternary expression instead of the detour with a temporary `bool k`.
4. some functions have poor error handling when the heap is empty, such as `extract_max`. In cases when function return value is a desirable usage pattern (as opposed to return by reference parameter), despite erroneous usage unable to return any reasonable value, I find it most simple to allow users to register a callback to be called on serious errors, and then return whatever is least probable to cause hard-to-find bugs in user code. On returning an integer this usually boils down to returning zero. Such a callback typically terminates the program, but user is also allowed to recover gracefully.
5. not sure about your requirements, but the `display` function printing to `cout` is useful in only very few cases. I prefer more flexible version where users provide their own "display" functions to execute for each element:

   ```
   void foreach(void f(int)) { 
       for(auto x: v) 
           f(x); 
   }
   ```

I find the code readable. Good job.

Comment: The last two points here sound like a C programmer's advice. (4) For error handling, throw an exception. The calling code can choose to catch it or not. Either way things stay clean, an no resources get lost. (5) Instead of `print`, overload the stream insertion operator. That way the user can choose which stream to write to. Also, it's idiomatic in C++, people will expect it to be present.

Comment: I have many years more experience of C++ than C, yet I have come to prefer C in most scenarios. Exceptions are the C++ way of doing it, and most would agree they come with a number of issues that really can't be solved. Overloading a stream operator is just a pain, but I guess some are code masochists getting payed by the line.

Comment: @Andreas, I believe the problem he is referring to are lack of templates and iterators. Especially in the last case, it could be templated on the `Callable` type. Upvoted anyway, since it has some good points.